# include xfail error info in pytest junit output?

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest's junitxml output records an xfailed test as skipped, but I can use the type (`<skipped type="pytest.xfail" message="" />`) in my tools to tell it's really xfailed.

What I'm missing is details on why it failed -- is there a way to get pytest's junit output to include the error, like it does for failed tests?

Specifically, in the example below I'd love if `asserting False in aaa` could appear in the output.

test_abc.py:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.xfail
def test_aaa():
    assert False, 'aaa xfails'

def test_bbb():
    assert False, 'bbb reall fails'
```

`pytest test_abc.py --junitxml=output.xml`

output.xml:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><testsuites><testsuite name="pytest" errors="0" failures="1" skipped="1" tests="2" time="0.154" timestamp="2022-02-12T08:27:20.645265" hostname="Davids-MacBook-Pro.local"><testcase classname="test_abc" name="test_aaa" time="0.001"><skipped type="pytest.xfail" message="" /></testcase><testcase classname="test_abc" name="test_bbb" time="0.001"><failure message="AssertionError: asserting False in bbb&#10;assert False">def test_bbb():
&gt;       assert False, 'asserting False in bbb'
E       AssertionError: asserting False in bbb
E       assert False

test_abc.py:9: AssertionError</failure></testcase></testsuite></testsuites>```
````

Comment: pytest.mark.xfail(raises=someerror) - try adding this.